# concurrent_queue in struct

Tags: c++, vector, queue

I want to create a connection struct with a concurrent_queue and a connection pointer in it. Since I have an unknown amount of connections, this struct will be pushed back in a vector.

The vector and struct:

```
        struct connection_struct {
            concurrent_queue<string> messages_queue;
            connection_ptr con;
            connection_struct(concurrent_queue<string> queue) {
                messages_queue = queue;
            }
        };

        std::vector<connection_struct> allConnections;
```

This can be compiled, but when I create the struct, it cannot be compiled anymore. I create the struct by:

```
                boost::thread_group message_workers;
                concurrent_queue<string> message_queue(&message_workers);

                connection_struct viewer(message_queue);
```

The compile error is huge, but I think this is the relevant bit:

```
In constructor ‘websocketpp::broadcast::handler<endpoint_type>::connection_struct::connection_struct(concurrent_queue<std::basic_string<char> >) [with endpoint_type = websocketpp::endpoint<websocketpp::role::server, websocketpp::socket::tls>]’:
broadcast_handler.hpp:284:21: note: synthesized method ‘concurrent_queue<std::basic_string<char> >& concurrent_queue<std::basic_string<char> >::operator=(concurrent_queue<std::basic_string<char> >&)’ first required here
```

Any clue what I should do? Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would help if you pasted the entire error message and told us where that `concurrent_queue` is from.

Comment: It appears that `concurrent_queue` is not assignable but, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355375.aspx, is copy constructable. So : `connection_struct(concurrent_queue<string> const& queue) : messages_queue(queue) {}`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, think about whether you *actually* want copies of your `concurrent_queue` (rather than *references* to them). Once you're sure you do, you can try the following (C++11, works with MS `::Concurrency` and Intel TBB as those `concurrent_queue`s are copy constructable):

```
connection_struct(const concurrent_queue<string> & queue) : message_queue(queue) {}
```